# Data from list into another list

Tags: c#, .net

It's a kind of placeholder for the user data.

```
public class UserDoa
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

The following method returns a UserDoa list.
This list contains all the users received from the database through a DataReader.

```
Database.Select.Users();
```

Next I have a User class.

```
public class User
{
    public User(........)
    {
        // perform a query like:
        Database.Create.User(........);
    }

    public void Remove()
    {
        // perform a query like:
        Database.Remove.User(someuser);
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can create a list of User with the data from UserDoa like:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();

users.Add(new User(........);
```

and

```
users[99].Remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to create a `User` for each `UserDoa`:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
foreach(var doa in Database.Select.Users())
    users.Add(new User{Id = doa.Id, Name = doa.Name});
```

or

```
var users = Database.Select.Users()
    .Select(x => new User{Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is there a way to kinda copy the UserDoa into the User class?

Comment: Add a variable to the user class - public userdoa doaInformation; Then you can "new User(doaInformation);" Make sure to update your constructor to take a variable and assign it to the internal variable.

Comment: Or just update your constructor - 
public User(UserDoa doaInfo) {
Database.Create.User(doaInfo.Id, doaInfo.Name);
}

Comment: @Yooouuri no, there's no built in way. You esentially have to fill the properties yourself (like shown in my answer). If you have to do this in a large number of places, a library like AutoMap might help. But for a couple of classes, I would just do it by hand.